# Setting up internal search on a website, how do I use the Meta Descriptor if there is no excerpt defined?

Tags: wordpress, divi

Using the popular Divi theme under Wordpress, I am trying to use the Yoast meta description as the snippet shown in an internal search result, if an excerpt is not defined. The internal search results in the first so-many characters of the webpage showing instead.

The code in question (as part of search.php in a child theme) is:

```
et_divi_post_meta();
    
if ( 'on' !== et_get_option( 'divi_blog_style', 'false' ) || ( is_search() && ( 'on' === get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_et_pb_use_builder', true ) ) ) ) {
        truncate_post( 270 );
        }
```

I was hoping to replace *_et_pb_use_builder* (which returns the page/post content) with *_yoast_wpseo_metadesc* but without success.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have any error?

Comment: I don't get an error. I just get the first 270 characters of the page content which includes menu like stuff rather than a nice description of the page as supplied by the meta description.